# Filter a list based on user input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of songs, and I want users to be able to filter them by typing into a text field. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
  $("#filter_song_list").keyup(function() {
    var filter = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");

    $("ul.song_list a").each(function(){
      if (!$(this).text().match(filter)) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
```

1. Is this the right approach?
2. Since I'm interpreting the user's input as a regular expression, he can't search for songs with (say) a period in the title without first escaping it ("."). How can I fix this while still maintaining the case-insensitivity of the search?

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to do what you ask for (not any better in terms of performance then your solution) is:

change filter to be the user input, not a regex.

change the filtering line to:

```
if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($.trim(filter.toLowerCase())) > -1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

[Escape your regex prior to executing it](http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/#c32703):

```
var pattern = $(this).val().replace(/([.*+?^${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
var filter = new RegExp(pattern , "i");
```

However you're just doing a case-insensitive search for a string within a string. You don't need regular expressions for this. @[mkoryak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401043/filter-a-list-based-on-user-input-with-jquery/1401057#1401057) is more suitable for you IMO.

I'd have said jQuery's [built-in `contains` psuedo selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) was perfect for you, but it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make a cached reference to your elements to speed things up:

```
var cache = $("ul.song_list a");
```

Then do a simple string match, using the jQuery `filter()` function, and `hide()` matched elements:

```
cache.filter(function ()
{
    return $(this).text().toLower().indexOf( <value from input> ) < 1;
}).hide();
```

The final snippet of code:

```
$(function ()
{
    var cache = $("ul.song_list a");

    $("#filter_song_list").keyup(function ()
    {
        var val = $(this).val();

        cache.filter(function ()
        {
            return $(this).text().toLower().indexOf(val) < 1;
        })
        .hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: it think you need to user .toLowerCase() instead. Also, tried ( http://jsfiddle.net/aegq4/10/ ) and i get all items hidden and never shown again, even if the input matches the text. Are you sure it should work? am i doing something wrong?